# How to write Junit test for to check data that I selected from DB and the Data that I have inserted in DB

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have Business component, Controller,Service,ServiceImpl. I have selected data from DB using stringBuilder and performed some calculations and inserted data from the variables that I took from DB. How to write Junit test for to check data that I selected from DB and the Data that I have inserted in DB?

Comment: Please add reference code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBUnit tool. Generally the tool is able to generate "expected" dataset from xml files, connect to database and retrieve "actual" dataset and check assertions.
Examples are here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dbunit